# Sed: How to replace pattern with file's contemt

Tags: linux, bash, text, replace

File 'sample.json' (JSON):

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "configuration.import",
    "params": {
       "format": "xml",
       "source": "REPLACE_ME_WITH_XMLSOURCE"
    },
    "auth": "91ea4764dcab42e8317b399c42985792",
    "id": 1
}
```

File 'source.xml' (XML, 1 long line with spaces and double quotes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><zabbix_export>...</zabbix_export>
```

Required result (JSON with XML as param's value):

```
    ...
   "source": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><zabbix_export>...</zabbix_export>"
...
```

I tried to place content of 'source.xml' to variable and use it in sed, but without success:

```
# x=$(cat source.xml)
# sed "s/REPLACE_ME_WITH_XMLSOURCE/$x/" sample.json
sed: -e expression #1, char 80: unknown option to `s'
# sed "s/XMLSOURCE/"$x"/" sample.json
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command
#  sed "s/XMLSOURCE/"$x"/" sample.json
...
```

I tried use sed '/REPLACE_ME_WITH_XMLSOURCE/ r source.xml' in variations, but my sed-fu is not enough to solve it..

I tried to google and search here, but.. you see this question..

Thanks for any advice

Comment: This issue related to [Zabbix API configuration.import](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/api/reference/configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# read the xml file into a variable
xml=$(< source.xml)
# perform the substitution, adding appropriate escaping of quotes
sed 's|\("source": \).*|\1"'"${xml//\"/\\\\\"}"'"|' sample.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something else than `/` characters to delimit the `s` command of `sed`. The slash is part of the substitution string and therefore it will confuse `sed`.
Try some other delimiter which is not part of the substitution string, e.g.:

```
sed "s|REPLACE_ME_WITH_XMLSOURCE|$x|" sample.json
```

Comment: shouldn't those double quotes in `$x` be escaped?

Comment: OMG.. in my script i use sed 2 times, and in first case there are pipe-delimeters ("|").. My mind seems to be damaged,
Thanks a lot

Comment: escaped double quotes in $x - are new problem:
`# x=$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s|\n||g; s|  \+||g; s|\"|\\"|g' Real-Exported-Template.xml)'
`# echo "$x"`
`<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>...`
`# sed "s|REPLACE_ME_WITH_XMLSOURCE|$x|" sample.json`
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...`

Comment: I think you might need one (or two?) more level(s) of backslashes.